# How did the sandworms and sandtrout appear on Arrakis?

Tags: dune, frank-herbert, sandworm

Were they native species?

My impression was that Arrakis was turned into Dune fairly recently, geologically/paleontologically speaking.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, they weren't a native species.  Leto Atreides II remembers via his Other Memory that long ago Arrakis used to be a wet planet, but after the sandtrout were introduced to the environment, they dried it up as part of their life-cycle.

> *"The sandtrout ... was introduced here from some other place. This was
> a wet planet then. They proliferated beyond the capability of existing
> ecosystems to deal with them. Sandtrout encysted the available free
> water, made this a desert planet ... and they did it to survive. In a
> planet sufficiently dry, they could move to their sandworm phase"*
>
> <sub><sup>Children of Dune</sup></sub>

There was evidence on Arrakis of this change, dried up lakebeds and such.

More information can be found on the [Dune fan wiki](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Sandtrout).  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandworm_%28Dune%29#Sandworm_life_cycle) indicates this information is in *Children of Dune*.