# Where did the Sandworms/Sandtrout originally come from?

Tags: dune, frank-herbert, brian-herbert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How did the sandworms/sandtrout appear on Arrakis?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3625/how-did-the-sandworms-sandtrout-appear-on-arrakis)

I'm going to ask a more pointed version of this question:

[How did the sandworms/sandtrout appear on Arrakis?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3625/how-did-the-sandworms-sandtrout-appear-on-arrakis)

Has anyone found any references that *explicitly state* exactly where the Sandworms came from?  Did either Frank or Brian give any clues?  Even the Dune Encyclopedia doesn't have an answer (I looked at my copy just now)

In Children of Dune, Leto II says that they were "introduced" to Arrakis, but he never says where they came from.

http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Sandtrout

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandworms_of_Dune

Comment: I've read _Children_ (too long ago, I'll admit), but I can't remember where Leto said that. Do you have a chapter?

Comment: Keen's answer on the question you linked provides 100% of known information. Details for the origin are never given anywhere.

Comment: @DVK - i don't see this as a duplicate, because Keen's question is how did they get there, not where did they come from, and I'm also asking if there are any references (cannon or not) from the Herbert clan giving any clues.

Comment: @SteveED - the rules for SE are that the Q is a duplicate if it can be fully answered by an answer for another Q, even if the question itself is different. Don't hate the messenger.

Answer (score 1):

I'll defer to DVK, and say that there are no references other than are already on this question:

[How did the sandworms/sandtrout appear on Arrakis?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3625/how-did-the-sandworms-sandtrout-appear-on-arrakis)