# Who introduced the Sandworms to Arrakis?

Tags: dune, sandworm

This question explores if the [Sandworms are native to Arrakis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3625/how-did-the-sandworms-sandtrout-appear-on-arrakis), which we know to be untrue.  This then raises a question.
**Who introduced the Sandworms to Dune?**

---

This [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69305/is-it-ever-explained-how-people-first-got-to-arrakis-before-they-had-spice) indicates how it may be done by humans, is there any mention in the prequels etc. of who put them there? A really nice bonus would be what species originally introduced the Sandworms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't know, the best we have was the other memory of Leto II stating that the worms were not native to Arrakis (information from Children of Dune).

We can reasonably say humans did it, since there is no other intelligent life encountered in the books, and the Worms are already in place Pre-Omnious (this knowledge appears in one of the 3 books in the Butlerian Jihad trilogy book 3 i belive battle of corino).

Comment: Without regard to Brain's non-canonical work, we can say that the Sandworms were in place significantly prior to the Battle of Corrin, or else the battle could not have occurred and the 1000 year period of Stagnation known as Landsraad might not have come into being.

Comment: @Lighthart i believe its been more like 10,000 years since the battle of Corrin, by the time Dune takes place. http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_(Expanded_Dune)